# Clone href attribute value to span with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wonder if someone can help me out? I want to clone the attribute values from each link and append to a span with jQuery.

**I have this code:**

```
<a href="http://www.site1.com">
<h3>Site1</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site2.com">
<h3>Site2</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site3.com">
<h3>Site3</h3>
</a>
```

**And I want do this:**

```
<a href="http://www.site1.com">
<span class="link">http://www.site1.com</span>
<h3>Site1</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site2.com">
<span class="link">http://www.site2.com</span>
<h3>Site2</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site3.com">
<span class="link">http://www.site3.com</span>
<h3>Site3</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Finding the `<a>` elements? Getting their `href` values? Creating new elements? Adding them to the document? Did you read the jQuery tutorial at all? All you need to know should be in there: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** and **[`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)**

1. **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method to iterate `a` tag
2. **[`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** to add content at the beginning

.

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend($('<span/>', {
    class: 'link',
    html: this.href
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.site1.com">
  <h3>Site1</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site2.com">
  <h3>Site2</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site3.com">
  <h3>Site3</h3>
</a>
```

Or you can iterate using **[`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** with callback

.

```js
$('a').prepend(function() {
  return $('<span/>', {
    class: 'link',
    html: this.href
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.site1.com">
  <h3>Site1</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site2.com">
  <h3>Site2</h3>
</a>

<a href="http://www.site3.com">
  <h3>Site3</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Or pass a function to `.preprend`: `$('a').prepend(function() { return $('<span/>', {class: 'link', html: this.href}); });`